# SQL - Select the top difference between 2 columns

Tags: php, mysql, sql, difference

I am looking for some queries to get the top difference between 2 columns, and return the column "name" and the difference between them.

I am using PHP (PDO) to do this with my MySQL database.

This is my table:

Table name = players.

```
+--------+--------+--------+
|  name  | score1 | score2 |
+--------+--------+--------+
| bob    |     10 |      5 |
| sarah  |      3 |      1 |
| george |      2 |      9 |
+--------+--------+--------+
```

As you can see, Bob has a difference of 5.
Sarah has a difference of 2.
And George has a difference of 7.

In this case, George has the highest difference between the 2 scores.
I therefore want to get George's name and the difference between the 2 scores.

So on my page, I should print the string: `George (+7)`

Also, if 2 or more has the same difference, it should pick the one with the highest `score1`. If multiple people have the same difference and `score1` then it should just pick any of them, it does not matter.

But how can I select the difference between these?

I have not found any documentation for this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `order by` and `limit`:

```
select t.*, (score2 - score1) as diff
from t
order by abs(score2 - score1) desc, score1 desc
limit 1;
```

Comment: and you might want to add `LIMIT 1` to that :)

Comment: Very clever! It worked perfectly! Holy shit! Whoever owns SQL and made it should hire you and build a function out of that, name it the Linoff function. I did not even know you could just add more `desc` to the query to sort off of other columns in case they are identical. Today I learned !!